# Unit Testing and Continuation-Local Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I would like to harness CLS (continuation-local storage) in my TypeScript app so that I have somewhere I can put metadata (e.g. user ID, request ID) for various uses (e.g. logging) without having to pass the data in each method call.

I have attempted to use both [cls-hooked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-hooked) and [async-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-local-storage). However, I haven't been able to get either working from my Jest unit test.

```js
const als = require('async-local-storage');
als.enable();

// ... some code

describe('Authorization tests', () => {
  test('Cannot call without correct scope', () => {
    als.set('id', "123123123123");
    expect(() => service.registerApp(ctxt, app)).toThrowError(AuthorizationError.NOT_AUTHORIZED);
  });
});
```

The above setting of the datum `id` does not fail.

```js
export function authorize(requiredPermissions: string[]) {
    return (target: any, name: any, descriptor: any) => {
        const protectedFunction = descriptor.value;
        const als = require('async-local-storage');
        console.log(`>>>>>>>>>My ID ${als.get('id')}`);

        // ... some code
    }
}
```

However the above code simply outputs:

```
>>>>>>>>>My ID null
```

Is what I'm attempting possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem without the need for the `jest-localstorage-mock` dependency. In short, my `get(...)` call was attempting to read the store before async hooks were enabled, which is a requirement according to [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html#async_hooks_asynchook_enable). Additionally, my `get(...)` call was attempting to read the store too early; because I'm attempting to do this in a decorator I need to move the `get` call into the `descriptor.value`, which is what actually gets executed at runtime.

My updated production code now includes the `enable()` call, the `get(...)` call is in the correct place, and all is well:

```js
const als = require('async-local-storage'); // pulled up to top of file
als.enable(); // added

export function authorize(requiredPermissions: string[]) {
    return (target: any, name: any, descriptor: any) => {
        const protectedFunction = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = function() {
            console.log(`>>>>>>>>>My ID ${als.get('id')}`); // moved into function
            // ... some code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jest doesn't seem to support localStorage, you'll need to mock it instead.

I'd suggest using a library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-localstorage-mock for this, as else you'd have to implement it all by yourself.

You'd need to add that library to your `devDependencies` and add it as a jest setupFile in package.json:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": ["jest-localstorage-mock"]
  }
}
```

Your tests should pass after that.